# WSL crontab cannot find nix-shell

Tags: linux

I have a simple shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -p python38Full -p python38Packages.virtualenv
#!nix-shell -I bash
source .venv/bin/activate
```

I schedule this script using crontab in WSL, but crontab outputs

```
/usr/bin/env: 'nix-shell': No such file or directory
```

But I can run "/usr/bin/env nix-shell" fine. Can someone explains this issue

Comment: Are you using the full path in your cron job?

Comment: Yes full path of this shell script

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem on macOS by checking the crontab-error-messages in `/var/mail/<username>`. It gives you some pretty useful information like:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=joe>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=joe>
```

It seems `crontab` uses its own very basic `$PATH` (probably because it's not using an **interactive** or **login-shell** so it skips over your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` or something similar).

Luckily `crontab`-files also support setting environment variables. Thus you can make `nix-shell` work if you manually add the path.

1. Edit your personal crontab file:

```
crontab -e
```

2. Add this PATH on one of the first lines (before the actual cronjobs) so the `crontab`-file looks something like this:

```
PATH=/full/path/to/.nix-profile/bin
5 0 * * * /run/this/script-with-a-nix-shell-shebang.sh
```

> Be careful about assuming the existence of `$HOME`- or `$USER`-variables. Check `/var/mail/<username>` after test-running your cronjob to debug. I ended up using an absolute path to my home-dir's `.nix-profile/bin`.